# Change weekend to weekday

Tags: r, date, xts, zoo, quantmod

I have a `dataframe`. Some dates fall on the weekend. However I would like to change all weekend dates to the past Friday.

```
 as.Date(aapl_earnings$Date, "%Y/%m/%d")
 [1] "2018-04-30" "2018-01-31" "2017-11-01" "2017-07-31" "2017-05-01" "2017-01-30" "2016-10-24"
 [8] "2016-07-25" "2016-04-25" "2016-01-25" "2015-10-26" "2015-07-20" "2015-04-26" "2015-01-26"
[15] "2014-10-19" "2014-07-21" "2014-04-22" "2014-01-26" "2013-10-27"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a nested `ifelse` here and check the day of the week using `weekdays` and adjust the date accordingly.

```
dates <- weekdays(as.Date(x))

as.Date(ifelse(dates == "Saturday", x - 1, 
        ifelse(dates == "Sunday", x - 2, x)), origin = "1970-01-01")

#[1]"2018-04-30" "2018-01-31" "2017-11-01" "2017-07-31" "2017-05-01" "2017-01-30"
#[7]"2016-10-24" "2016-07-25" "2016-04-25" "2016-01-25" "2015-10-26" "2015-07-20"
#[13]"2015-04-24" "2015-01-26" "2014-10-17" "2014-07-21" "2014-04-22" "2014-01-24"
#[19]"2013-10-25"
```

---

Or we can also use `case_when` from `dplyr` which is more verbose.

```
library(dplyr)
aapl_earnings <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(x))

aapl_earnings %>%
     mutate(date = weekdays(Date), 
            new_date = case_when(date == "Saturday" ~ Date - 1, 
                                 date == "Sunday" ~ Date - 2, 
                                 TRUE ~ Date)) %>%
     select(-date)

#         Date   new_date
#1  2018-04-30 2018-04-30
#2  2018-01-31 2018-01-31
#3  2017-11-01 2017-11-01
#4  2017-07-31 2017-07-31
#5  2017-05-01 2017-05-01
#6  2017-01-30 2017-01-30
#7  2016-10-24 2016-10-24
#8  2016-07-25 2016-07-25
#9  2016-04-25 2016-04-25
#10 2016-01-25 2016-01-25
#11 2015-10-26 2015-10-26
#12 2015-07-20 2015-07-20
#13 2015-04-26 2015-04-24
#14 2015-01-26 2015-01-26
#15 2014-10-19 2014-10-17
#16 2014-07-21 2014-07-21
#17 2014-04-22 2014-04-22
#18 2014-01-26 2014-01-24
#19 2013-10-27 2013-10-25
```

**data**

```
x <- c("2018-04-30","2018-01-31","2017-11-01","2017-07-31","2017-05-01",
    "2017-01-30","2016-10-24","2016-07-25","2016-04-25","2016-01-25","2015-10-26",
    "2015-07-20","2015-04-26","2015-01-26" ,"2014-10-19","2014-07-21","2014-04-22",
    "2014-01-26", "2013-10-27")
```